# Who invented salt, and why is it called salt?

Tags: hash, reference-request, password-hashing, salt, history

I'm looking for an authoritative reference about the history of salts in the context of hash functions. Why is the personalization string in a hash function called a "salt"? Who should be credited with introducing this technique?

So far I have found:

- Plenty of speculative folk etymology on the [Wikipedia discussion page for salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Salt_(cryptography)#Etymology)
- The earliest academic reference to salt I can find is [Password Security: A Case Study](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359168.359172) by Robert Morris & Ken Thompson, from 1979.
- According to the source code at the [UNIX Heritage Society](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl), salted passwords seemed to be added in V7 UNIX, released in 1979 (`passwd.c`: [V7](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/passwd.c) vs [V6](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/source/s2/passwd.c)). The source code already refers to the technique as salt, in its use of variable names. Was this the first use of the salt technique anywhere?

Comment: I think the sentence from Morris and Thompson's article ; _"the 12-bit random
quantity (called the salt)"_ indicates that either they named for the article or it was internally named in the Bell Labs. They could give a reference easily if it is written somewhere,

Comment: I wonder this does Ken Thompson still reply e-mails?

Comment: Found [this article](https://media.thinkbrg.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/11184031/Kalat_Legaltech_nov19.pdf) which lends a level of historical imprimatur.